# Display csv file in flask

Tags: python, csv, flask

Python code:

```
@app.route('/history')
def history():
    return render_template('history.html')
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <h2>History</h2>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 2px black solid;
                font: 12px sans-serif;
            }

            td {
                border: 1px black solid;
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="d3min.js?v=3.2.8" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='d3min.js') }}""></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
            d3.text("output.csv", function(data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the csv file:

```
15.3C   94.90%  7/3/2017 1:29
15.2C   94.90%  7/3/2017 1:59
14.8C   94.90%  7/3/2017 2:29
14.7C   95.00%  7/3/2017 2:59
14.8C   95.00%  7/3/2017 3:29
14.8C   95.00%  7/3/2017 3:59
14.6C   95.00%  7/3/2017 4:29
14.8C   95.00%  7/3/2017 4:59
14.5C   95.00%  7/3/2017 5:29
14.8C   95.00%  7/3/2017 5:59
14.1C   95.00%  7/3/2017 6:29
14.4C   95.00%  7/3/2017 6:59
16.0C   90.80%  7/3/2017 7:29
16.4C   90.00%  7/3/2017 7:59
17.2C   89.90%  7/3/2017 8:29
18.1C   87.20%  7/3/2017 8:59
```

I'm trying to display a .csv file in flask, the file is in the same place as the html file but does not show the content of it. The values in csv are separated by commas. If I open the history page in firefox, without flask server, it displays the values in a table.
[image: Table with values from csv]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
<script src="/static/d3min.js" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='d3min.js') }}""></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
            d3.text("/static/output.csv", function(data)
```